# React Router: How to match indeterminate amount of sub paths of a nested route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a file explorer like Dropbox. There will be an indeterminate amount of subpaths that look like this:

`localhost:3001:file-manager/folder1/folder2/...folderN`

I have this:

`<Route path="/file-manager/:folderName" component={LandingPage} />`

This allows me to visit: http://localhost:3001/file-manager/foo/bar/baz. However, when I check `props.match` I don't see it, it only shows a match for `foo`, not the levels below that (bar and baz).

```
match:
isExact: false
params: {folderName: "foo"}
path: "/file-manager/foo"
url: "/file-manager/foo"
```

How would I do this? All the tutorials I'm reading and watching about recursive routes *append* to the view. I want to *replace* the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem a few months ago. I can't find the exact code I used at the moment, but if I recall correctly you can use an asterisk to indicate "everything from this point on" which includes any further path separators:

```
<Route path="/file-manager/:folderName*" component={LandingPage} />
```

This does mean that `props.match.params.folderName` will be the full string, so you'll have to split it by `/` yourself if you need an array of path components.

Important note: the `*` will make it match anything, so if you have a specific route you want to match, make sure you put it *before* this one, e.g.

```
<Route path="/file-manager/example" component={ExamplePage} />
<Route path="/file-manager/:folderName*" component={LandingPage} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what's happening is somehow correct since you're only defining one level of nested routes in the route declaration:

```
<Route path="/file-manager/:folderName" component={LandingPage} />
```

Therefore the first path param that is found (in your case `foo`) is matched against the `folderName` property, while others are ignored.

I've never done a thing like this but I can only imagine it to work using a dynamic route definition. Of course this works only if your app will render the same component for all the routes generated since the first one.

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/:folderName`} component={LandingPage} />
```

Something like this should prevent the problem you reported. But you must put an external route definition to start the route recursion. And in this case yours is going to be good.

```
<Route path="/file-manager/:folderName" component={LandingPage} />
```

You can find a similar thing over [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/advanced-react-router-concepts-code-splitting-animated-transitions-scroll-restoration-recursive-17096c0cf9db/) at the chapter `Recursive Routes`.

Hope this helps!